# Windows Hotspot has No Internet Access at Work

Tags: internet-connection, wireless-access-point, hotspot

I am creating a hotspot from my wired LAN connection for my phone using mHotspot. It works at my home network but not at my office. I am using the same laptop on both networks.

What is different at my Work that is making it not work? Its a similar LAN network like at my home.

How to fix this? I have tried creating the hotspot manually as well works fine at home not in office.

OS: Windows7, Laptop

Comment: While I agree with the answer that exists at this time, your question is missing info.  What hardware are you using to create the hotspot?  Is it the same laptop at home and work? or different computers at home and work?  What OS?  How specifically did you create the hotspot that works at home?  Where specifically does the process fail at work?  Do you see error messages?

Comment: Yes its the same laptop....  I have installed mHotspot. I am on Windows7. While from the laptop you just plugin the lan cable an access the internet. They why is the hotspot not able to pick it up. Note, I have made sure the Lan is shared to the wireless connection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to talk to your IT department at work. They almost certainly have security controls on what devices can connect to their network.

- If someone connected a virus-infected device, it could easily infect their whole network.
- They need to guard against theft of the company's confidential information.
- They also need to protect themselves from someone using their network for other illegal activity.